# Spring: Scoped fields

Tags: java, spring

I wrote this idea on the Spring JIRA and even though I know this is not a key feature and has minor priority, I'd still expect some answer by now. I publicize the idea, because I want to know what you guys think about it, if it's cool and I should implement it myself, or is the need for this is a sign of bad architecture.

So the idea itself is - as the title suggests - is a field in a Spring Bean, which has a different scope then the bean itself. We already have something like this, in the shape of scoped proxies, however it works only for bean dependencies. I might want to store a list of Strings of session scope in a bean of singleton scope. I, then have to create a new bean, with scope of session for one field and some functions to use that field. It seems a waste of code and I'd find it bad, because I wouldn't be able to use that bean anywhere else, because it'd already have that data the first class put into it.

I could rephrase the mess above and say that I want to have named beans with arbitrary type (so not necessarily spring beans) and on top of the scope we configure it to have, that field would also be different for every instance of the parent class.

This could make a field instance broader than a prototype scoped bean, but also less broad then the actual scope we'd like to use it in. Kind of a middle ground.

Here is the JIRA issue I wrote: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16971

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, Scopes only work with Dependency Injection as it's the DI Container that decides if it should return a new instance or an already existing one. So everything that is @Autowired can be scoped.
I can't imagine how scoping a normal field would work. If I change it, should it change in all other objects that "use" it? I would have to be some kind of proxy object then and neve a primivive value. If on the other hand you have a proxy object, why not use the currently available autowire mechanism.

Comment: It would probably be implemented with some kind of proxy, yes. However, the current autowire mechanism can only inject spring beans. I wouldn't want to create a spring bean to have a string for example.

Also, it's different, because autowire wires in instances independent of the class declaring the field, which makes it gimmicky in some use-cases, where you want 2 different strings in 2 different beans